# Inexpensive way to protect outdoor metal table from rust?

Tags: rust, rust-proofing

I recently purchased an outdoor metal table with powder coating that is *supposed* to protect it, but I know that it won't last.

What inexpensive product can I apply to the surface of the table to protect it even more from the rust, but also not change its look? I prefer something "watery" or very low viscosity.

Comment: You really can't. Corrosion occurs when coatings fail, usually as a result of thermal cycles, impact, abrasion, etc. Not much will prevent that to a greater degree than the existing coating already does.

Comment: Powder coating is usually one of the _best_ metal protection options there is.

Answer (score 4):

Powder coating, done well, not scratched, chipped or flaked - actually works.

So, if it meets those standards, you don't need to apply anything - the cheapest and most transparent of coatings.

Hopefully the particular powder coat is suitable for outside use and won't degrade in the sunlight. Plenty of them are.

If it was done poorly or you have handled the table carelessly and chipped or scratched through the coating, it will rust. The magical product you want does not exist, so at that point you can have the  powder coating re-done, or have it stripped and hot dip galvanized, or move on to regular doses of rust removal and paint application.

Comment: And to help protect from chipping in use, a glass top or a table cloth may help.